# Return type as a two dimensional array

Tags: c, calloc

The following piece of code gives an error for conflicting types of function fun2() when compiled.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char ***  fun(){
    char *** b;
    calloc(10,sizeof(char **));
    b[0]=fun2();
    return b;
}

char ** fun2(){
    char **a;
    a=calloc(10,sizeof(char*));
    a[0]=calloc(10,sizeof(char));
    return a;
}
main(){
    char **c;
    c=fun();
}
```

However, this piece of code does not -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char ***  fun(){
    char *** b;
    calloc(10,sizeof(char **));
    b=fun2();
    char **a;
    a=calloc(10,sizeof(char*));
    a[0]=calloc(10,sizeof(char));
    return a;
}

main(){
    char **c;
    c=fun();
}
```

But, both the program are doing the same task. What is the reason behind the compilation error?

Comment: Is the second snippet complete? I don't see definition for `fun2()`.

Comment: The second one leaks memory in the first two lines of fun().

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the first code snippet is that `fun2()` has not been defined or declared before its first use. The compiler generates an implicit function declaration that returns an `int` however the actual definition of `fun2()` returns a `char**`, which is the cause of the conflicting type compiler error. To correct the conflicting type error you can either place the definition of `fun2()` or place a declaration of `fun2()` to prior the definition of `fun()`.

Note that the return value of some `calloc()` calls are *not* being assigned to any variables.

Just to mention that `calloc()` sets all bits zero, which according to the C99 standard:

> Note that this need not be the same as the representation of floating-point zero or a null pointer constant.

So the use of `calloc()` to `NULL` the pointer arrays *may* be incorrect (in practice I don't know if this is ever the case). The alternative is to explicitly assign `NULL` to each element in a pointer array.

Comment: I'd go with the former - there is no overhead in declaring prototypes for all functions in the module header, but it makes it clear what you are defining.

Comment: Piling on that, in the main, `c` is declared as a `char**` but `fun` is declared as returning a `char***`, the compiler should also warn about that.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler hasn't seen the definition of `fun2()` yet. You must either declare the function in front of fun2():

```
char ** fun2();

char ***  fun(){
...
```

or move fun2() before fun():

```
char ** fun2(){
...
}
```

Be aware that you haven't assigned a value to `b` in both cases and the allocated memory by `calloc()` is lost. You should modify this to:

```
char *** b = calloc(10,sizeof(char **));
```